# Integral expansion of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Trying to understand where eqn 1.127 comes from]

Can anyone please explain how eqn 1.127 is derived?

Answer (score 2):

Think of the transformation that makes A diagonal. Change to the basis of the eigenvectors of A. The integral becomes the product of M Gaussian integrals, which you can do. Remember that the product of the eigenvalues is detA.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The proof goes as follows:

Note that for a symmetric matrix, $\textbf{A}$, the determinant is the product of eigenvalues:

$$ \det\textbf{A} = \prod_{i = 1}^{dim\textbf{A}}{\lambda_i} $$

To see this, we eigendecompose $\textbf{A}$. The columns of $\textbf{C}$ are the eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$, $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with its diagonal entries being the eigenvalues of the corresponding eigenvectors:

$$ \textbf{A} = \textbf{C} \Lambda \textbf{C}^T $$

Then, using $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$, and noting that the orthogonality of eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix results in $CC^T = I$, we obtain the first equation by taking the determinant of $\textbf{A}$.

Now, we use the standard result of the Gaussian integral:

$$   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda x^2 \right) dx} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}}  $$

With this we can write:

$$        (\lambda_1\lambda_2...\lambda_{dim\textbf{A}})^{-1/2} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^{dim\textbf{A}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}...\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{dim\textbf{A}}{\lambda_i x_{i}^2}   \right] dx_1 dx_2 ... dx_{\dim\textbf{A}}}            $$

Notice that the integrand is in quadratic form:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{dim\textbf{A}}{\lambda_i x_{i}^2} = \textbf{x}^T\Lambda\textbf{x} $$

We now revert bases:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{dim\textbf{A}}{\lambda_i x_{i}^2} = \textbf{x}^T\Lambda\textbf{x} 
 =  \phi^T\textbf{A}\phi = \sum_{i,j=1}^{dim\textbf{A}}{\phi_i \phi_j A_{ij}} $$

Where $\phi= \textbf{Cx}$ is the transformed basis. Substituting this expression back  into the expression 2 lines above, and noting that the left-hand side is simply $\text{det}\textbf{A} ^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ gives the result, equation (1.127) in the original post (*note, the Jacobian of the transformation is 1, so the volume element of the integral does not change*).